# Qore: how to convert a hash to object

Tags: qore

How can I convert a `hash` to and `object`? Suppose I have the following definition:

```
class A {
    int i;
    string s;
}
class B {
    int bi;
    A a;
}

hash h = (
    "bi" : 100,
    "A" : ("i" : 10, "s" : "str"));
```

is there any way how I could convert `h` to an object of class `B`?

Answer (score 2):

Is this to be generic?  If so, then you'd need a bit more verbose structure.  Such that would make it clear that 'A' is to be an object, 'i' is to be an int, etc.

Anyway, there's a built-in function `create_object` that can be used to create an object as long as the object does not need constructor arguments or you know what they should be.  Then you would set all members and that means they need to be public.  You could also iterate object's public members and thus check if your hash provides all info.

I'm not aware of a way how to learn more about an object, such as member types, method signatures, etc.  Still, you either know the object (so you can provide args to constructor or call a method after creation etc) or it has to be a simple object with no constructor args and public members (as private members cannot be set directly).

Comment: links: [create_object()](https://docs.qore.org/current/lang/html/group__object__functions.html#ga6a929dc065cfb0b20639ac815be9cad3), [create_object_args()](https://docs.qore.org/current/lang/html/group__object__functions.html#ga4a7d04160dbbaf788cd8a0e18f28019c);  also there is an issue open relative to this question: [implement a way for objects to serialize and deserialize themselves](https://github.com/qorelanguage/qore/issues/1589)